# Snowflake - how to connect to Snowflake using NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone has a working code to connect NodeJS and Snowflake.

Tried following [instructions for NodeJS](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html):

```
var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');

var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: 'account1',
  username: 'user1',
  password: 'pass1',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

connection.connect(function(err, conn) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully connected as id: ' + connection.getId());
  }
});
```

Keep getting errors:

```
Network error. Could not reach Snowflake.
```

Similarly - following [instructions for Python](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html) works without problem (using EXACT same user/pass/account etc. as for NodeJS):

```
import snowflake.connector

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='user1', 
    password='pass1',
    account='account1'
)

print ("SELECT current_version():")
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one = cs.fetchone()
    print(one[0])  # 2.50.2
finally:
    cs.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

The account that use in python has "account_id.region" something like

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='user1', 
password='pass1',
account='abc.us-east-1'
)
```

For node.js you need to give the same as:

```
var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: 'abc',
  username: 'user1',
  password: 'pass1',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Aneesha! I was having the same problem trying to connect using Spark. I first used the python client where the account is actually "account'+'region", and account for spark is simply the account. 
That is such a crazy concept. Please keep same standards on the different platforms.

Answer (score 3):

my config worked for me:

```
 var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
   account: 'abc.us-east-1',
   username: 'user1',
   password:'pass1',
   authenticator: 'SNOWFLAKE',
   clientSessionKeepAlive: true,
});

connection.connect( 
    function(err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
            } 
        else {
            console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
            // Optional: store the connection ID.
            connection_ID = conn.getId();
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: adding authenticator: 'SNOWFLAKE', and clientSessionKeepAlive: true, worked for me too !!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the region from the connection information and specify 'account='abc.us-east-1'.  The region field is being deprecated and should not be used in connections to Snowflake.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#establishing-a-connection

Answer (score 0):

Based strictly on code provided, the functional difference between the 2 examples is that the Node.js one specifies the `us-east-1` region, and the Python one does not specify a region. The default region is us-west-2, which does not need to be specified. The linked documentation notes: "use only if your account is not in US West". So specifying an incorrect region could cause connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the cloud provider as well as the region, so in my case it was:

```js
const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
   account: 'abc.us-east-1.aws',
   username: 'user1',
   password:'pass1',
   authenticator: 'SNOWFLAKE'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample connection object that helps to connect to snowflake database

```
// Create a Connection object that we can use later to connect.
var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
    account: "abc.east-us-2.azure", //'abc' - change as per the your instance
    username: "username1", 
    password: "pwd1",
    //warehouse: "warehouse_name", // optional
    //role: "role_name", // optional
    //schema: "shema_name", // optional
    //database: "DB_name" // optional
  });
```